# Git merging remote branch to another remote branch - Best practice

Tags: git, github

Here's the scenario -

- The project is on Github
- I'm working with a team on a shared feature branch (*feature-branch*)
- I want to merge the feature branch into another branch... say *master*

My normal workflow would be:

`git checkout feature-branch`

`git fetch`

`git rebase` (now my local is up to date with other's changes)

`git checkout master`

`git rebase` (now my master is up to date)

`git merge feature-branch`

`git push` (both updated master and local feature-branch are pushed)

I discovered that someone else on my team was doing things differently and were merging directly from remote/feature-branch to local/master.

What is the best practice here? Should we be using one method over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two operations are equivalent. If you merge from the remote though, you don't have to be careful that your local `master` branch is up to date.

My workflow is typically:

```bash
git checkout feature-branch
git fetch
git rebase # if there are upstream commits on the feature branch
git merge origin/master
git push
```

Comment: Cool, I'm going to switch to merging from the origin. It seems like a safer workflow.